# nuxt3、laravelでfetchするときのqueryについて

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

検索formから検索したい条件を複数選択してuseFetchのqueryに設定したのですが、
現状のフローが以下のような流れになります。

1. 検索条件選択（マルチセレクトもあります）
2. 検索ボタン押すと検索一覧ページに遷移(navigateToにquery設定)
3. 一覧ページでURLのqueryを取得しuseFetchでget

#### 問題点

useFetchで422 Error が発生する。

navigateToで設定されるURLが `https://domain/search?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=1&d=3&d=4&e=2000000`
laravel側でd=1&d=3&d=4の形式ではなく、`d[]=1&d[]=3&d[]=4` の形式でないといけないらしいのですがnavigatoToのqueryでformatを変更できる方法はありますか？

#### 現状のコード

検索ボタンのmethod(dataは検索条件でformコンポーネントからemit)

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const search = (data:any) => {
  return navigateTo ({
    path: "/search",
    query: "data"
  })
</script>
```

検索一覧ページscript

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const route = useRoute()
const { data:searchItems } = await useFetch("path", {
  query: route.query
})

</script>
```

設定するdata

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const params = {
  a=1,
  b=2,
  c=3,
  d=[1,3,4],
  e=2000000,
}

</script>
```